# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. Redux

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I keep getting dispatch error with redux/ typescript. Would be great if someone can help correct the setup I have here:

Store:

```js
import {
  configureStore,
  combineReducers,
  MiddlewareArray,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

//import slice as reducer
import userReducer from './features/userSlice'
import heroReducer from './features/heroSlice'
import menuReducer from './features/menuSlice'
import utilsReducer from './features/utilsSlice'
import templatesReducer from './features/templatesSlice'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  //combine all reducers
  user: userReducer,
  hero: heroReducer,
  menu: menuReducer,
  utils: utilsReducer,
  templates: templatesReducer,
})


export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: new MiddlewareArray(),
})

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
```

where the dispatch is happening:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      // TODO
      dispatch(fetchUser()).  <--- error portion
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

user slice:

```js
import { createSlice, createSelector, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/fetchUser',
  async (thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/user', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      // return rejectWithValue({ error: error.message })
      return console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
)

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    userData: {},
    isSubscribed: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    setUserData: (state: any, action: any) => {
      state.userData = action.payload.userData
    },
    setIsSubscribed: (state: any, action: any) => {
      state.isSubscribed = action.payload.isSubscribed
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUser.fulfilled, (state: any, action: any) => {
      state.userData = action.payload
      state.isSubscribed = action.payload.isSubscribed
    })
  },
})

export const userData = createSelector(
  (state: any) => ({
    userData: state.userData,
    isSubscribed: state.isSubscribed,
  }),
  (state: any) => state.userData
)

export const { setUserData, setIsSubscribed } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer
```

Not too sure what else is needed to get rid of type errors?

Original error:

Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Type Error on dispatch(fetchUser())

```
'Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction''
```

npm ls redux shows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `middleware: new MiddlewareArray()` removes all middleware from the store - while usually a few would be included. Among them is `redux-thunk`, which allows for the dispatch of thunks.

Change it to:

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
})
```

By the way you also don't need `combineReducers`, so you can do

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
    hero: heroReducer,
    menu: menuReducer,
    utils: utilsReducer,
    templates: templatesReducer,
  },
})
```

Comment: this seems to fix the middleware issue though I still get type error on the dispatch(fetchUser()) Is this bug with TS? updated question with npm ls + error

Comment: if you used `useDispatch` to get that `dispatch`, it would still give a TS error, if you used `useAppDispatch`, it should not

Comment: ah ok got it-- converting useAppDispatch + useAppSlector to hook to resolve issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is that there is no middleware available to receive thunks, specifically the `fetchUserUser` thunk that you are dispatching.

The call to `new MiddlewareArray()` likely returns an empty middleware array which does not include the thunk middleware.

To introduce such middleware, you can do so in the following ways when configuring your store:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

...

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk] // add the thunk middleware
})
```

OR alternatively, you may use the [`getDefaultMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) callback, which includes the same thunk middleware from 'redux-thunk' alongside other helpful serializability- and immutability-check middleware in development. Find more docs on this here.

This is what that would look like:

```
...
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware() // includes the thunk middleware
})
```

Comment: Or just leave it out completely to get the defaults either way ;)

Comment: Ahh. Got you. I was not aware that it came as part of the store by default! Good to know that now ;)